# Drag /Drop possible in LEx-WEB-UI?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

In addition to the default Lex slot types, would it be possible to do add a custom step on the chat bot - for instance, request a user to upload a file or photo (and store it on S3), then return to the Lex flow?e ? Any idea or approach it appreciated ?

Comment: upload a file for what?

Comment: To get the data from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer would likely depend on where you are hosting your Lex application. You could use the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk) of your choice (I'd use the [PHP SDK to upload to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html), in my case, on a Drupal 7 website). From there you would just detect the intent that requires the photo upload, once detected you would allow the user to upload their image client-side, and could use the AWS SDK to put the image into your S3 bucket. You could then validate the file prior to loading into S3, and program the bot to respond with appropriate message, based on successful, or unsuccessful upload (i.e. if file is too large or not correct aspect).

This would likely require a Lambda function, but not necessarily, if you're using the AWS SDK server-side you could do file validation, processing and from their instruct your lex chatbot to respond appropriately. This stack is [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210568/can-amazon-lex-chatbot-accept-image-as-input). Here is an example using [Node](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-set-up-simple-image-upload-with-node-and-aws-s3-84e609248792). I hope this helps!