# Can amazon lex chatbot accept image as input ?

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex, amazon-rekognition

I want to build a deep learning chatbot application which accepts image as input. 
I have built a lambda function integrating AWS rekognition that accepts image.Now, i want to extend this lambda function, and connect it to Amazon Lex bot , where user can upload the image for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lex Chatbot can't accept image but **Its possible** by Integrate your **Amazon Lex Bot** with **Amazon API Gateway**.

- Your application API call to the HTTPS endpoint hosted by
  AWS API Gateway.
- API Gateway deal With Lambda function.
- Lambda function runs your business logic and uses the PostText/PostContent to communicate with your Chatbot or call AWS Rekognition service on completion call your Chatbot using Lambda function.
- You will get response.

[More Details.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/integrate-your-amazon-lex-bot-with-any-messaging-service/)

Comment: is there any specific example that you can share on how to take image as input for the lex bot.